# Syscall argument in kprobe with wrong value libbpf

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ebpf, kprobe

I'm trying to use libbpf to trace calls to the kill syscall. Here is my eBPF program:

```c
SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_kill")
int BPF_KPROBE(__x64_sys_kill, pid_t pid, int sig)
{
    bpf_printk("Pid = %i\n", pid);

    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason, when I try to read the `pid` argument, the value is negative. But when using strace on the `kill` command the value of pid is positive.

```sh
$ ping 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null &
[1] 87120
$ strace kill -9 $(pidof ping)
...
kill(87120, SIGKILL)                    = 0
...
[1]+  Killed                  ping 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null
```

Logs:

```
bash-83960   [001] d... 42409.690336: bpf_trace_printk: Pid = -1060765864
```

I can't figure out why the value of the `pid` argument insde the eBPF program is not the same as the one given by the urserland process

Comment: What's the value of `sig`?

Comment: Looking into this, I think there's supposed to be a `struct pt_regs *ctx` argument first. This would make sense, since kernel addresses are negative.

Comment: > What's the value of sig?
88350 ...

I'm using libbpf so there is no ``struct pt_regs *ctx``, [see](https://facebookmicrosites.github.io/bpf/blog/2020/02/20/bcc-to-libbpf-howto-guide.html#kprobes). I've try to use it anyways using PT_REGS_PARM* like so:

`SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_kill")
int bpf_kill(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
 bpf_printk("Pid = %i, Sig = %i\n", PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx),
     PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx));

 return 0;
}
`

... but the result is the same as the other one in the post

Comment: Well, regardless of *what* the first argument is, the variable called `kill` is clearly what's supposed to be the PID. Just insert the dummy argument (maybe as a `void*` if it seems nonsensical) and then ignore it; don't do the PT_REGS_PARM stuff.

Comment: There is no variable called `kill`. The `__x64_sys_kill` is just a name for the [macro expansion](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/8bf016110e683df2727a22ed90c9c9860c966544/src/bpf_tracing.h#L421). So the real (for what I understand) first argument is `pid_t pid` ... which does not have a correct value

Comment: I can reproduce but haven't found a way to fix it so far, for what it's worth your program looks good to me but maybe I'm missing something obvious :/. If I adapt [killsnoop from bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/10dac5fcdecd1afee08a3918feb744abeff81432/tools/killsnoop.py#L66) to do the same thing as your sample program it works as expected, I guess one way to proceed could be to compare the instructions from both and see where they diverge :/.

Comment: Intresting. I'm new to eBPF, have you some resources for dumping the eBPF bytecode ?

Comment: `bpftool prog dump xlated <program>` (See [man page](https://www.mankier.com/8/bpftool-prog), maybe [this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/qeole/status/1101450782841466880) I did). From an object file it would be `llvm-objdump -S my_program.o`, but that won't do with bcc since you don't get the object file.

Answer (score 0):

For Syscalls try using "ksyscall/kill"

What happens is your kernel was probably compiled with the flag for wrapping syscalls, you can read more about that in the kernel code.